# Quantify stationary seasonality

Tags: time-series

I want to quantify seasonal variation to be able to determine that one data has more seasonal variation than another data.

I am analyzing weekday variation in sales for a stores (Store A ). I have data between 1995 and 1999 and 2005 and 2009.

My aim is to identify and compare the daily Seasonality in 1995-1999 and 2004-2009.

I have worked with seasonality before, but I have never used any method to quantify seasonality.

I have identified the seasonal components using the `decompose()` function in R. 
I run two separate models, one for 1995-1999 and one for 2004-2009. 
I use additive models because the seasonality does not vary within these periods. 
I report the results as seasonal index.

It is easy to see (Figure below) that there was less seasonality in 2005-2009 (dotted line) compared to 1995-1999 (solid). 
However, I would like to be able to quantify the difference in seasonality. 
Is it correct to use a simple Coefficient of variation (CV)? CV in 1995-1999 = 0.15. CV in 2005-2009 = 0.5.

[image]

Comment: No expert on time-series analysis but the CV seems like an appropriate measure here.

Comment: See the strength of seasonality measure defined here: https://otexts.com/fpp3/stlfeatures.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

strength of seasonality

[small vs. large seasonality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zn50q.png)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibD44.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zn50q.png)

I have read about the strength of seasonality and wonder about what it really indicates. What is the meant of strength of seasonality? feat_stl() function i r produce seasonal_strength. But is this really an indicator of how **much** seasonality a seasonal pattern holds? Is strength = "how much"

Is not the total area under/above the line of seasonality a better measure of increasing/ declining seasonality. The blue line obviously symbolizes much more seasonal variation compared to the red line. If you measure the arena below/above the lines, these areas also clearly shows this.

Is measuring the total area above/below the line a working way to quantify seasonal variation?

I understand that it can be more complex if the seasonal pattern is very fluctuating because that is also part of seasonal variation.